# Value of column, based on function over another column in Matlab table

Tags: matlab

I'm interested in the value of result that is in the same row as the min value of each column (and I have many columns, so I would like to loop over them, or do rowfun but I do not know how to get 'result' then).

**Table A**

```
+----+------+------+----+------+------+--------+
| x1 | x2   | x3   | x4 | x5   | x6   | result |
+----+------+------+----+------+------+--------+
| 1  | 4    | 10   | 3  | 12   | 2    | 8      |
| 10 | 2    | 8    | 1  | 12   | 3    | 10     |
| 5  | 10   | 5    | 4  | 2    | 10   | 12     |
+----+------+------+----+------+------+--------+
```

Solution

```
8   10  12  10  12  8
```

I know that I can apply rowfun, but then I don't know how to get result.
And then, I can do this, but cannot loop over all the columns:

```
A(cell2mat(A.x1) == min(cell2mat(A.x1)), 7)
```

and I have tried several ways of making this into a variable but I can't make it work, so that:

```
A(cell2mat(variable) == min(cell2mat(variable)), 7)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is homogeneous you can use [`table2array`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table2array.html) and the second output of [`min`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) to index your results:

```
% Set up table
x1 = [1 10 5];
x2 = [4 2 10];
x3 = [10 8 5];
x4 = [3 1 4];
x5 = [12 12 2];
x6 = [2 3 10];
result = [8 10 12];
t = table(x1.', x2.', x3.', x4.', x5.', x6.', result.', ...
    'VariableNames', {'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'result'});

% Convert
A = table2array(t);
% When passed a matrix, min finds minimum of each column by default
% Exclude the results column, assumed to be the last
[~, minrow] = min(A(:, 1:end-1));

solution = t.result(minrow)'
```

Which returns:

```
solution =

     8    10    12    10    12     8
```

From the documentation for `min`:

> `M = min(A)` returns the smallest elements of `A`.
>
> `<snip>`
>
> - If `A` is a matrix, then `min(A)` is a row vector containing the minimum value of each column.